# $\sum^\infty_{n=2}{\frac{2^n + (-1)^n}{4^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

How do you find the value of this series?

$$\sum^\infty_{n=2}{\frac{2^n + (-1)^n}{4^n}}$$

I tried writing out the series at $n=2, n=3,$ and $n=4$, and I attempted to look for a pattern with which to take the limit as $n \rightarrow ∞$. However, I couldn't find this pattern.

Are there any other methods by which to find the sum of a series? Is there any rigorous and mathematical method through which to find the $n$th term of the series?

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty\frac{2^n + (-1)^n}{4^n}$?

Comment: Whoa how did you do that?

Comment: MathJax. I can edit your question for you if it is indeed the correct expression.

Comment: It is the correct expression. Is MathJax a program that allows one to type math on a browser?

Comment: It's more of a language that allows one to format equations, not just on a browser.

Comment: @user3776574, take a peek at http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

*** If $\;|q|<1\;$ , the sum of a geometric series is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n=\frac1{1-q}$$

$${}$$

$$***\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n+(-1)^n}{4^n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for finite case:
if $r\neq 1$ then,

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}r^{i}=1+r+...+r^{n}=\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

remember that your sum starts from 2 so, do not forget subtract first 2 terms at the end..